# Cygwin kore make can't find socket.h

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin to make the makefile of kore.io on Windows 10 and get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wsign-compare -Iincludes -std=c99 -pedantic -DPREFIX='"/usr/local"' -O2 -c src/kore.c -o obj/kore.o 
src/kore.c:20:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/kore.o] Fout 1
```

I've looked around, but none of the solutions I found worked for me.

I checked the Cygwin /usr/include/sys folder and did find socket.h.
I read through the makefile and don't see anything wrong with the lib references.

I've been trying to get this work for over an hour now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To find which package you need to install, use cygcheck to find the package containing `sys/socket.h`

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/include/sys/socket.h
Found 5 matches for usr/include/sys/socket.h
cygwin-devel-2.6.1-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files (installed binaries and support files)
cygwin-devel-2.7.0-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-2.8.0-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin32-2.5.2-1 - cygwin32: Cygwin 32bit toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
cygwin32-2.6.0-1 - cygwin32: Cygwin 32bit toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
```

So you need to install `cygwin-devel` that contains the `cygwin` standard headers.